# OnPointerHold interference with Scroll Rect scrolling

Tags: unity-game-engine

A simplified example of my problem - I used Unity UI to create the following:

[image]

A large panel, containing a list of smaller panels. I have attached a Scroll Rect to a container game object, thus making the smaller panels scrollable horizontally. No problem there, everything works as expected.

However, I have a script attached to each of the smaller panels, which implements the OnPointerHold interface. Now when I try to scroll through the smaller panels, the OnPointerHold event is fired, blocking the scrolling for some reason.

Any ideas as to why this happens?

My real case is that I need to have a scrollable list of images, which can be dragged onto the scene if the player taps & holds them. I'm using OnPointerHold to detect the tap & hold - if 0.7 seconds have passed, then let the player drag the image. However, I still want the player to be able to scroll through the list. I'm open to other suggestions on how to achieve that.

Thanks in advance, keep up the good work!

Comment: I dont think this is good idea, as imagine that user is draging very slowly keeping finger of one of the images - 0.7s passed and he starts to drag but he didnt want it. But to fix this just cancel drag action when scroll rect changed position significantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement only `IPointerDownHandler` and `IPointerUpHandler` interfaces. As long as you don't implement the drag or hold handlers, drag and hold events should pass right through to the `Scroll Rect`.

To use `IPointerDownHandler` and `IPointerUpHandler` for your purpose just count time from begining of `void OnPointerDown (PointerEventData eventData)` was called, and if no `void OnPointerUp (PointerEventData eventData)` is called in given time (0.7sec), move out the image from `Scroll Rect` and attach to some canvas, and update its position to pointer position.

Also this solution is good because if you start dragging the `Scroll Rect`, the `void OnPointerUp (PointerEventData eventData)` will be called which is good as, you want to drag `Scroll Rect` in given time (0.7sec).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Jerry Switalski! You're absolutely right, IPointerDownHandler and IPointerUpHandler don't interfere with the scrolling action of a Scroll Rect. I re-wrote my code like you said and everything seems to be working just how I want it.